# How does MSMA kill crabgrass with only minimal damage to lawn grasses?

Tags: botany, toxicology

I use [MSMA](http://stonebrothers.com/shop/msma-6-plus-herbicide-5-gallons/) (Monosodium methyl arsenate) to kill crabgrass in lawns. I am not certain of the mode of action.

[image]

How does this chemical work? How does it target the annual grassy weeds, without damaging the lawns much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please consider this a sort of comment — I tried looking up for articles related to MSMA mode of action but almost all the articles are about its toxicity in mammals.

By what I understand, trivalent arsenates act as phosphate analogs and therefore interfere in phosphorylation reactions including DNA synthesis [<sup>[Ref]</sup>](http://ipmworld.umn.edu/chapters/whitacreherb.htm).

The weed is affected perhaps because of its relatively higher growth rate. Also the already established lawn grasses would have good population size to regrow out of the damage.